# What happens to the blockchain after the miner wins the puzzle?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, proof-of-work, consensus

I have some problems understanding the flow of consensus mechanism, so far I know, In PoW when validating a transaction the miners will compete with each other to solve a puzzle, the miner who find the nonce first will get the chance to validate.

My problem is, I don't understand the process after this. I want to know what miners will do after solving the puzzle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is, I don't understand the process after this. I want to know what miners will do after solving the puzzle?

After miner A found the nonce, he broadcasts his "solution" to the network (miner B and miner C for example) and starts to build a new block and try to find the new nonce.

Miner B and miner C both validate the "solution". If it's a correct block, they add it to their local blockchain and broadcast it to others (Miner D, E, F...) and right after that, they do also build a new block and try to find the new nonce for that one.